# How to fire didChangeDependencies() of a particular StatefulWidget that is a child of PersistentTabView screens list (PersistentTabView)

Tags: flutter, dart, navigationbar, provider

What is the process to fire initState(), didChangeDependencies() every time I am switching my item.

I am showing some ads on my Timeline() and that ads can be saved (isSaved = true), using provider. Problem is, When I am switching to the SavedAds(), first time it is showing me the correct saved items. But if I go to the Timeline() and save some more, SavedAds() not updating even If I used provider to listen the saved ads.

I also noticed it is not firing  initState(), didChangeDependencies() every time I am switching to a new Screen(), How can I fire  initState(), didChangeDependencies() when I switch to a new Screen()

My Home Screen

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar/persistent-tab-view.dart';
import 'package:women_home/GLOBALS.dart';
import 'package:women_home/screens/home/timeline.dart';
import 'package:women_home/screens/saved/savedAds.dart';

class HomeCore extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "/homeCore";
  @override
  _HomeCoreState createState() => _HomeCoreState();
}

class _HomeCoreState extends State<HomeCore> {
  late PersistentTabController _controller;

  List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
    return [
      Timeline(),
      Container(),
      Container(),
      SavedAds(),
      Container(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(),
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
        title: ("Home"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bubble_left),
        title: ("Messages"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bell),
        title: ("Notifications"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart),
        title: ("Saved"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person),
        title: ("Account"),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: GLOBALS.appBgColor,
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _buildScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Default is Colors.white.
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
        stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
        ),
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
        itemAnimationProperties: ItemAnimationProperties(
          // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
        screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
          animateTabTransition: true,
          curve: Curves.ease,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        ),
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is SavedAds()

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:women_home/GLOBALS.dart';
import 'package:women_home/providers/PropertyAd.dart';
import 'package:women_home/screens/home/SinglePropertyAd.dart';

class SavedAds extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SavedAdsState createState() => _SavedAdsState();
}

class _SavedAdsState extends State<SavedAds> {
  late List<PropertyAd> _savedAds;
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("init fired");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print("fired");
    setState(() {});
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _savedAds = Provider.of<PropertyAds>(context).getSavedAds();
    print("build fired");
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: GLOBALS.appBgColor,
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _savedAds.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: _savedAds[i],
            child: SinglePropertyAd(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```